# Pandas: make groupby output as a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find `quantile(.25)` for each version group in my data frame like below:

```
a=df.groupby('version')['duration'].quantile(.25)
a

version   duration

4229     1451.00
6065      213.75
9209      386.50
2304      664.50
6389        1.00
7952      153.25
8833        1.00
4799      612.50
3457      762.00
9069      602.50
8415     1480.75
0783      553.00
7014        0.00
9134        1.00
2233     1442.00
5649      569.75
9818     1446.00
4218      285.50
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

I am wondering how could we make `a` in the format of pandas data frame? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nested brackets,

```
df.groupby('version')[['duration']].quantile(.25)
```

Or, with `to_frame`:

```
df.groupby('version')['duration'].quantile(.25).to_frame()
```

Or, with `reset_index` (this brings the index out as a column):

```
df.groupby('version')[['duration']].quantile(.25).reset_index()
```